# Remote file access on Mac

Tags: node.js, server, webstorm, remote-access, remote-server

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8t9j.png)I want to make modifications (code changes) to a js file on a droplet server. I know where the file is located on the server but I do not know how to open/change said file to include my modifications.

Ideally I would like to open the file in WebStorm and be able to make changes to it there, but I have no idea how to do that. I do not know what commands I would have to run to do such a task.

I connect to the server using terminal by running (ssh root@server ) and typing in the required password.

Comment: *"I connect to the server using terminal by running (ssh root@server )"*. Try Deployment functionality via SFTP (if yuo have SSH access then you *may have* SFTP as well). Once defined you can connect to your SFTP and edit your file right from the server. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/settings-deployment.html , https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/deploying-applications.html , https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/create-ssh-configurations.html

Comment: @LazyOne what commands would I have to run? I think I have sftp

Comment: @LazyOne my one MAIN issue is that this is my first time using Webstorm and I have NO IDEA how to open a remote server file on webstorm. Every web source I use just tells me to use SFTP and I already set up SSH configuration and the Build, Execution, Deployment to the server I want but I do not know how to open the actual file on webstorm itself. When I open Webstorm, I get 3 options, create new project (I dont wanna create a new project), open (which only lets me pick files from local machine not remote server) and get from version control (which Idk how to use), check image for details.

Comment: 1) WebStorm (as well as any other JetBrains IDE) works with projects. You need to create some project in order to use Deployment functionality. So just create some. 2) Once you create a deployment, use "Tools | Deployment | Browse Remote Host" to see remote system. You can then just double click on desired file, IDE will download that file for you (outside of the project) and allow you to edit it. Once you finish with editing, just hist the "Upload" button.

Comment: 3) I strongly suggest to have a local copy of your project -- it will allow to use all IDE features (because it can then index your code and libraries used and can offer code completion/different inspections based on that). If you do not need any of that .. then you better just use some advanced editor and not an IDE.

Comment: Some links: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/deploying-applications.html (watch video about deployment functionality). https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/deployment-in-phpstorm.html. Remote edit: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/editing-individual-files-on-remote-hosts.html. It's for PhpStorm .. but it's the same for WebStorm as well.